# Extract comma seperated Value using regex in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have following as input

```
Str := "Name1 Surname1 (AB123), Name2 Surname2 (MN456), Name3 Surname3(xy789)"
```

Required out put

```
AB123,MN456,xy789
```

I am using following regex in oracle

```
SELECT TRIM (
          REGEXP_SUBSTR (
             'Name1 Surname1 (AB123), Name2 Surname2 (MN456), Name3 Surname3(xy789)',
             '[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3}',
             1,
             1,
             'i'))
  FROM DUAL;
```

Which returns me only value `AB123` I want all with comma separated.

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so complicated answers...

There is much more simple one:

```
select rtrim(regexp_replace('Name1 Surname1 (AB123), Name2 Surname2 (MN456), Name3 Surname3(xy789)',
                            '([^\(]+?\(([[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3})\))','\2,',1,0,'i'),',')
from dual;
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
A bit changed version:

```
select rtrim(regexp_replace('Name1 Surname1 (AB123), Name2 Surname2 (MN456), Name3 Surname3(xy789)',
                            '[^\(]+?\(([[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3})\)','\1,',1,0,'i'),',')
from dual;
```

Comment: Hey Simon can you pls explain above answer as I am new to REGEX. From first look it seems that you are replacing everything except AB123 from Name1 Surname1 (AB123).

Comment: yes, that's right! `[^\(]+?\(` means everything until "(", `([[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3})` is your expression enclosed into "()" to be used as \2, and `\)` is the end of current block (which you have 3 in this case)

Comment: by the way, outer () are not needed: can be removed, and \2 should be changed then to \1. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this, tried on Oracle 10.2:

```
SELECT regexp_replace
       (
        'Name1 Surname1 (AB123), Name2 Surname2 (MN456), Name3 Surname3(xy789)'
       ,' ?\w+ \w+ ?\(([^)]+)\)'
       ,'\1'
       ) as col
  FROM dual;
```

Comment: What's different? It gives me the string: AB123,MN456,xy789 - seems to  be what he wants.

Comment: yes, it works for this example, I am not offending your solution, even like it, but the author's definition is to get all the values which match this: _[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3}_

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22003)

**Query 1**:

This is how to do it using a replacement with regular expressions:

(and some edge-cases to test against - `NULL` surnames, suffixes added to surnames and double-barrelled surnames)

```
WITH strings AS (
            SELECT 'Name1 Surname1 (AB123), Name2 Surname2 (MN456), Name3 Surname3(xy789)' AS str FROM   DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Madonna  (MA001), John Jones(Jr) (JJ001), Doctor Doctor(PhD) (dd001), Alf Double-Barrelled (AD001)' AS str FROM   DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( str, '.*?\(([[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3})\)\s*(,|$)', '\1\2' ) AS match
FROM   strings
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22003/0)**:

```
|                   MATCH |
|-------------------------|
|       AB123,MN456,xy789 |
| MA001,JJ001,dd001,AD001 |
```

**Query 2**:

This is how to do it using a hierarchical query:

```
WITH str AS (
  SELECT 'Name1 Surname1 (AB123), Name2 Surname2 (MN456), Name3 Surname3(xy789)' AS str
  FROM   DUAL
),
lengths AS (
  SELECT str,
         REGEXP_COUNT( str, '\(([[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3})\)\s*(,|$)' ) AS len
  FROM   str
)
SELECT SUBSTR(
         SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (
           REGEXP_SUBSTR (
               str,
               '\(([[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3})\)\s*(,|$)',
               1,
               LEVEL,
               NULL,
               1
           ),
           ','
         ),
         2
       ) AS match
FROM lengths
WHERE LEVEL = len
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= len
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22003/1)**:

```
|             MATCH |
|-------------------|
| AB123,MN456,xy789 |
```

**Query 3**:

If you are using a version of Oracle which pre-dates `REGEXP_COUNT` then you can use a combination of `LENGTH` and `REGEXP_REPLACE` in its place; like this:

```
WITH str AS (
  SELECT 'Name1 Surname1 (AB123), Name2 Surname2 (MN456), Name3 Surname3(xy789)' AS str
  FROM   DUAL
)
SELECT str,
       REGEXP_COUNT( str, '\(([[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3})\)\s*(,|$)' ) AS len,
       LENGTH( REGEXP_REPLACE( str, '.*?\(([[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3})\)\s*(,|$)', 'X' )) AS len2
FROM   str
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22003/2)**:

```
|                                                                   STR | LEN | LEN2 |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|-----|------|
| Name1 Surname1 (AB123), Name2 Surname2 (MN456), Name3 Surname3(xy789) |   3 |    3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the regex, use capture group 1 to get the content of the parens:

```
\((.{5})\)
```

Check it out here: http://regexr.com?37kq7

Answer (score 0):

A little ugly for sure and works only on Oracle version >= 11.2 (because LISTAGG was introduced since that):

```
SELECT LISTAGG(COL1, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 1) RESULT
  FROM (SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Name1 Surname1 (AB123), Name2 Surname2 (MN456), Name3 Surname3(xy789)',
                                  '[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3}',
                                  1,
                                  ROWNUM,
                                  'i')) COL1
          FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT('Name1 Surname1 (AB123), Name2 Surname2 (MN456), Name3 Surname3(xy789)',
                                         '[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3}',
                                         1,
                                         'i'));

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AB123,MN456,xy789
```

**Note:** The above works with any occurences of pattern in input string.

**UPDATE:** For versions 9i, 10g, 11.1 you can use [STRAGG user function](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402) contributed by Tom Kyte. Also  as it was mentioned in the comments there is WM_CONCAT function.

Comment: you can use `WM_CONCAT` for 10g

Comment: Sure, there is also stragg by Tom Kyte. I will add it to the answer. Regarding performance issues it is all relative. Let's look at another solutions and compare.

Comment: check my answer, I think it is much simpler and faster

Answer (score 0):

Not terribly nice, but works.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE 
('Name1 Surname1 (AB123), Name2 Surname2 (MN456), Name3 Surname3(xy789)',
'^.*?(\([^)]*?\)).*?(\([^)]*?\)).*?(\([^)]*?\))','\1,\2,\3')
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: and what if I add one more "Name3 Surname3(xy789)"?

Comment: The you would have to modify the regular expression.

Comment: regular expression should be like a constant - independent of the input